# jQuery not working with my HTML at all?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, apache

So, my jQuery doesn't do anything, neither if I do it with apache nor when I open it normally. (Chrome)

I linked it in the HTML, which is connected to my CSS, but it just doesn't do anything. Not entirely sure if that is because I didn't link it correctly or something. Here's all my code: (Bonus question: Why isn't the list at Tournament Results Centered on the page?)

Thanks a lot guys!

Home.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Niki Stoiber</title>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/Niki/script.js'></script>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css'/>
    </head>
    <body>
            <div id="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <a href="Home.html"><li class="pull-me">Home</li></a>
                    <a href="AboutMe.html"><li class="pull-me">About Me</li></a>
                    <a href="Tournaments.html"><li class="pull-me">Tournament Results</li></a>
                    <a href=""><li class="pull-me">Social Networks</li></a>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div id="title">
                <h1 align="center">Niki Stoiber</h1>
            </div>
            <p>Hey there, my name is Niki Stoiber, and this is my Webpage!</p>
            <p>I am a 9 year old boy from Austria and I want to be a professional tennisplayer someday.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

AboutMe.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Niki Stoiber</title>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css'/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="navbar">
            <ul>
                <a href="Home.html"><li class="pull-me">Home</li></a>
                <a href="AboutMe.html"><li class="pull-me">About Me</li></a>
                <a href="Tournaments.html"><li class="pull-me">Tournament Results</li></a>
                <a href=""><li class="pull-me">Social Networks</li></a>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div id="title">
                <h1 align="center">About Me</h1>
        </div>
        <div align="center">
            <p>
            Age: 9 <br>
            Birthday: 14.4.2003 <br>
            Tennis Club I play for: <a href="http://better-tennis.at"> Better Tennis <br>
            <img src="http://bit.ly/WpoXB1"/></a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Tournaments.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Niki Stoiber</title>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css'/>
    </head>
    <body>
            <div id="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <a href="Home.html"><li class="pull-me">Home</li></a>
                    <a href="AboutMe.html"><li class="pull-me">About Me</li></a>
                    <a href="Tournaments.html"><li class="pull-me">Tournament Results</li></a>
                    <a href=""><li class="pull-me">Social Networks</li></a>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div id="title">
                <h1 align="center">Tournament Results</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        Anif, Salzburg: 9. Platz
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Goetzis, Vorarlberg: 1. Platz
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Imst, Tirol: 2. Platz
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

stylesheet.css:

```
* {
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    background-color:#D3D3D3;
    font-family:"Lintel", sans-serif;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Lintel";
    src: url("./Lintel.ttf") format("truetype");
}
#navbar {
    position:fixed;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-254px;
}
ul {
    vertical-align:auto;
    list-style-type:none;
    position:fixed;
    margin:-5px;
    text-align:center;
}
.AboutMe {
    font-family:"Lintel", Sans-serif;
}
ul a li {
    background-color:#2F4F4F;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    border-radius:5px 5px;
    border:solid black;
    font-family:"Lintel", Sans-serif;
    display:inline;
    padding:5px;
    z-index:1;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
#title {
    z-index:2;
}
a:link {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
}
a:visited {
    text-decoration:none; 
    color:black;
}
a:focus {
    text-decoration:none; 
    color:black;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration:none; 
    color:black;
}
a:activ {
    text-decoration:none; 
    color:black;
}
h1 {
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
}
p {
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
}
```

script.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).fadeTo('slow', 1);
    });
    $('a').mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).fadeTo('slow', 0.5)
    })
});
```

Comment: You need to reference the jQuery library --  https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide

Comment: Are you sure you referenced the jquery from your pages? just add this to your headers:  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Btw the best additional tip is to use.. http://html5boilerplate.com/ well build framework for all your markup...
Put scripts at the bottom, and use the right meta tags and so on

And as @tymeJV says ref jquery lib

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you're using jQuery ( the $ part ) without first including the jQuery library. The recommended way to do so is via Google Libs

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

as for the other question, why did you expect the list to be centered? I don't see any code for that.

Comment: @user2115623 Remember to add it before your script incl. and maybe add a link to your website.. :) then we can inspect what the problem is

Comment: @Simon Petersen so the order matters, okay, that's the problem. Also, this is currently only on localhost, so you won't see much at localhost/Niki/Home.html ;) But thanks a lot for the fast answers!

Comment: @user2115623 true Look into the html5boilerplate its a nice framework for all your code... Javascript libs need to go before the code that uses the libs its like to go to a libery to get a book that they dont have yet... :)

Answer (score 3):

It seems you forgot to import the jQuery library. Add this

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

inside your head tag

Comment: be sure to include it before the line in which you reference script.js

Answer (score 2):

CHANGE

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css'/>
```

TO

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css'/>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
```

Comment: `jquery.js` must insert before `script.js`